# Нужна ли запятая после вводного слова (может) и перед присоединяемым союзом (и)?

Tags: пунктуация

Пример: ...а, может и наоборот.

Answer (score 1):

Из предложенного фрагмента ("а может и наоборот") нельзя заключить, что "может" - вводное слово; можно лишь утверждать, что запятая после союза "а" невозможна. Запятая же после этого слова **может понадобиться** - в случае, когда "**может**" - сокращение от "**может быть**":

> Может быть, это полезно, **а может, и наоборот** (, вредно).
>
> Возможно, он примет положительное решение, **а может, и наоборот** -
>   откажет.

**А может и наоборот**, не понадобиться (если "может" сделать сказуемым):

> Он может принять положительное решение, **а может и наоборот, отказать**.

Пример с запятой из книжки:

> На севере милой Италии,
>
> **А может, и наоборот** -
>
> На юге прославленной Галлии, ...
>
> *(Аркадий Застырец, Белый китель, Litres, 2017)*